# Quiero importar Datos desde varias columnas de Tabla Tqlserver hacia igual cantidad de textbox(columnas) en form con un click en datagridview vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2014

Quiero importar Datos de una fila de varias columnas (33) de Tabla Sqlserver (TablaMantenimientoProductos) hacia igual cantidad de textbox en Form (para Editar), seleccionando con un click en Datagridview que tiene las mismas 4 primeras columnas con los mismos datos de otra tabla (TablaListaDeProductos(CODE, CATEGORY, PRODUCTS, IMPORT)) con Visual Basic (.Net). Muestro mi Código, sin el origen de la Base De Datos SQL, el Procedimiento `MostrarDetallesMantenimiento()` es llamado desde el evento CellContentClick del Datagridview.

```sql
Sub MostrarDetallesMantenimiento()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-DBR5PTF\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=BD_AgroQuimicaSolutions; Integrated Security=True")
    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TablaMantenimientoProductos WHERE CodeProduct=" & Me.DGVMantenimProducts.SelectionMode & "", conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        If ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Me.txtCodigoBarra.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
            Me.txtCodigoProductos.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
            Me.DTPickerFecha.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
            Me.cmbCategPrincip.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
            Me.cmbCategSecund.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
            Me.txtMarcaProduct.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(5).ToString
            Me.txtNombreCompProduct.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
            Me.RadButVentaxBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(7).ToString
            Me.RadButVentaxUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(8).ToString
            Me.RadButVentaxKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(9).ToString
            Me.RadButVentaxLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(10).ToString
            Me.cboPresentacion.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(11).ToString
            Me.cmbElegirBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(12).ToString
            Me.txtEquivUnidBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(13).ToString
            Me.txtCantBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(16).ToString
            Me.txtCantUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(17).ToString
            Me.txtCantKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(18).ToString
            Me.txtCantLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(19).ToString
            Me.lblTotalUnidades.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(20).ToString
            Me.txtStockMinim.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(21).ToString
            Me.txtPrecCompBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(22).ToString
            Me.txtPrecVentBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(23).ToString
            Me.txtPrecCompUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(24).ToString
            Me.txtPrecVentUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(25).ToString
            Me.txtPrecCompKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(26).ToString
            Me.txtPrecVentKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(27).ToString
            Me.txtPrecCompLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(28).ToString
            Me.txtPrecVentLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(29).ToString
            Me.txtPercepBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(30).ToString
            Me.txtGanancBolsa.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(31).ToString
            Me.txtPercepUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(32).ToString
            Me.txtGanancUnid.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(33).ToString
            Me.txtPercepKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(34).ToString
            Me.txtGanancKilo.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(35).ToString
            Me.txtPercepLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(36).ToString
            Me.txtGanancLitro.Text = ds.Tables("TablaMantenimientoProductos").Rows(0).Item(37).ToString
        End If

        MsgBox("Successfully retrieved")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("User is Not")
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Disculpen si no especifiqué puntual el problema,. Al hacer Click en el Datadridview me muestre en los textbox(37) los datos de la fila del Datagrid desde la tabla Sql server con la misma cantidad de columnas. Gracias

Comment: Al ser información relevante, debes agregar tu comentario como edición a la pregunta @Rangerarbsoft. Los comentarios son efímeros.